# Whats the meaning of CHANGEME in K8s helm charts?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

While checking the values of yaml files for a helm chart, one often encounters
`changeme` passed as a value. E.g.:

```
  rabbitmq.conf: |-
    ##username and password
    default_user={{.Values.rabbitmq.username}}
    default_pass=CHANGEME
```

or:

```
  config:
    accumuloSite:
      instance.secret: "changeme"
    userManagement:
      rootPassword: "changeme"
```

What is the meaning of "changeme"?

- Is it just a word that needs to be replaced? If so, what will happen if it is not? A security hole, or hopefully an error?
- Or is it a keyword that lets the system to replace this with a secure password? If so, how does the system know what type of password to produce?

In either case, how does the chart connect this value with other places where this value might be needed? ( e.g. if this is a password another -dependent to the first- service needs, how is the manually assigned / derived password propagated to the second service?  )

(*mainly interested about helm v3 if this is important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd almost always expect this to be just a placeholder that needs to be filled in.  In many cases YAML can wind up having inconsistent types if a value is actually absent, so it can be useful to have *some* value in the chart's `values.yaml`, but for things like passwords there's not a "right default value" you could include.

Nothing will automatically replace these for you or warn if you're using the default values.  Nothing bad will obviously happen if you do deploy with these values, but I'm sure `changeme` is up there with `passw0rd` on the short list of default passwords to try if you're actively trying to break into a system.

If you were writing your own chart, you could also test if a value is present using [`required`](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-required-function) and explain what's missing, and this approach might be more secure than having a well-known default password.